# Meteor up mup deploy fails

Tags: meteor, bcrypt, node-gyp

EDIT: 
Opened issue in Github repo. 
https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/87

I have tried to setup Meteor up to run a meteor app.

Here is the error I get when I run `mup deploy`

Invoking deployment process: FAILED

```
    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
    e-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /opt/give/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt
    gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! bcrypt@0.7.8 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.7.8 install script.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
    npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
    npm ERR! cwd /opt/give/tmp/bundle/programs/server
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /opt/give/tmp/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/give/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node ./build.js

    `linux-x64-v8-3.14` exists; testing
    Binary is fine; exiting
    fibers@1.0.1 node_modules/fibers

    > bcrypt@0.7.8 install /opt/give/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/bcrypt
    > node-gyp rebuild

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also ran a `mup logs -n 300` and got this response.

```
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/give/app/main.js does not exist.
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you run `mup setup` before?

Comment: Yes, I did run ```mup setup``` before.

Comment: getting this as well.

Comment: I had this issue yesterday after deploying to the the server for the 10th time. Before that, it always went smooth but now I ran into that bcrypt issue. I am running a on a small free AWS 30 gigabyte Ubuntu machine. Could it be that it ran out of diskspace? Because every mup deploy creates temp data and is not cleaned up? How else could the deployment fail after many successful deployments in the last 2 days. Really weird

Comment: @Mattijs run df -h, is there space left?

Comment: Yeah, I did that command yesterday. There was 28 gb free of the 30gb. So I have no idea what happened. Yesterday I was able to deploy again after having the instance shutdown for a day (and received a new IP address from AWS). So very strange issue. Hope it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I restored my server to an earlier state, reinstalled mup and set the install nodejs to false. I also installed node v0.10.29 using `sudo npm install n -g` `sudo n stable` and ran through `mup init`, `mup setup`, `mup deploy` works this time.